# Difference between recently dispatched and sent messages in ECM Messages

Tags: ecm

Does anyone know the difference between recently dispatched and sent messages displayed in Email Campaign Manager(ECM) Messages?

Comment: You should use Slack- https://sitecorechat.slack.com/ to ask such queries.

Comment: @RohitKakde The Sitecore slack channel does not maintain a history, so for posterity's sake it's much better to ask it here.

Answer (score 1):

"Recently dispatched" shows any email campaigns where the state is "Sent" or "Sending".

"Sent messages" only shows email campaigns where the state is "Sent".

Comment: Sorry i was asking about ECM(Email Campaign Manager). But I think ECM is almost similar to EXM. There are different type of messages in the home page of ECM. I am talking about the item /sitecore/system/Modules/SPEAK/EmailCampaign/Messages/RecentlyDispatched and /sitecore/system/Modules/SPEAK/EmailCampaign/Messages/SentMessages. What is the difference betwwen these two items. Is it like recently dispatched refers only top messages dispatched?

Comment: @user8927358 The answer haas been updated. ECM and EXM are very different, so thanks for clarifying.